# UML Tool for Windows

Tags: windows, uml

I'm looking for a UML modeling  tool.

The requirements are:

- User-friendly to be used.
- If any possible that the application is free to use.
- Enable to print out the diagram with less manual work.
- For Windows.
- When you have created the model, the application should enable to create the model automatically.

Information:
I'm using Visual Studio 2013, Windows Presentation Foundation and C#.

Answer (score 5):

> **StarUML** is an open source project to develop fast, flexible, extensible, featureful, and freely-available UML/MDA platform running on Win32 platform. The goal of the StarUML project is to build a software modeling tool and also platform that is a compelling replacement of commercial UML tools such as Rational Rose, Together and so on. (from: old projects of [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/v1), this project has been discontinued).

This tool supports **UML 2.0**, Model Driven Architecture, and Plug-in Architecture (C++, Delphi, C#, VB, ... modules). As your request, StarUML has **C#** Profile, Code Generator and Reverse Engineer. You can generate **documentation** automatically using Microsoft Office. It's **free**. See [here.](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/v1/about-2.php)

The good news: StarUML starts the new version project (since long time no updates).

[**StarUML 2**](http://staruml.io/) is the new project from *MKLab* as the next version of **StarUML v1**. The new version is compatible with **UML 2.x** standard and supports totally 11 kinds of UML diagrams. You can easily find and install extensions from Extension Registry. Moreover, anyone can write extensions using HTML5, CSS, JavaScript and Node.js. Open APIs allows to add Menus, UI, Dialogs, even new modeling languages (e.g., ERD, BPMN, SysML, etc.). StarUML 2 provides completely new platform-neutral **user interfaces** (Dark Theme, Quick Edit, Dialogs) while keeping **usability**, **simplicity**, and modern design trends. (taken from http://staruml.io).

Comment: "It's free". -> Not anymore. Sadly.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that you've visited [List of Unified Modeling Language tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools)

In that page you can see **Visual Paradigm for UML**

- This tool has been chosen by computer lecturers in my school based in their experience
- I think that it fits all of your requirements
- It's actively supported
- You can download a [community edition](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/community.jsp)  (free)

Answer (score 2):

[Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/) is an online editor that is free for limited use (single user, max number of objects). I've used it for smallish projects and it works well.

On the desktop side of things, I've always used MS visio. The newer versions are pretty good and have more functionality than you will likely ever need.

Visual studio also has a UML modeling utility. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409445.aspx). Not sure if it comes with every version, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements should fulfill [Software Ideas Modeler](https://www.softwareideas.net/).

- It supports all UML diagram types
- You can print or export your diagrams by one click
- Source code can be generated from the model/diagram
- It offers free Standard edition for non-commercial use
- It is actively developed for many years and it gained many interesting features over these years

[image]